# Estruturar conteúdo de um curso

Tags: html, css

Sou iniciante tanto HTML quanto CSS. Como podem ver na imagem preciso de ajuda para resolver 3 problemas:

1- Divisória da esquerda eu pretendo fazer uma espécie de menu (ou dividsórias) que serão os módulos do meu curso esse menu listará (aula1, aula2) na vertical..

2- Eu gostaria de a partir do momento que eu clico em um dos módulos o conteudo do modulo abra no lado direito. A pagina pode recarregar ou não (nao sei qual é possivel fazer)...

3- Além do mais esse conteudo ele é grande então eu gostaria de dividi-lo de modo que possa se passar com a seta as parte como se fosse um slide (pensei em fazer um iframe, mas não sei como fazer pra passar estruturar pra passar o conteúdo.)

Gostaria de ajuda para solucionar estes 3 problemas, de modo que eu evite usar PHP ou javascript porque ainda não comecei a aprender.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seja bem-vindo! Recomendo que faça um [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e leia sobre [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Tua questão é muito ampla e não há código para uma ajuda pontual.

Comment: Isto são várias questões e probelmas numa só pergunta.

Comment: Realmente você vai ter de usar javascript,  vai precisar de uma biblioteca chamada slick caroussel https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ , onde é possível obter esse slide, também fazer com que o slide seja apresentado conforme o modulo clicado, caso sobre tempo irei responder essa pergunta, mas é bom já ir estudando e tentando fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema 1:

Você pode usar o `Bootstrap`, ele possui uma classe `col` que pode ser usada para isso, já podendo deixar responsivo [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp).

Problema 2:

Sem javascript fica complicado, mas você pode usar o `:hover` para trocar o display dos slides (`none` e `inline`), porém não ficará muito bom

Problema 3:

Como você é iniciante sugiro o uso do [WOWSlider](http://wowslider.com/pt-br/) para criar esse "PowerPoint"

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado pela dica. Porém, percebi que o slide limitaria muito o meu conteudo. Então aprendi um pouco de JavaSCript e percebi que posso fazer exatamente o que eu gostaria usando um script básico:

```
function mostra() {
document.getElementById('introduçao').style.display = 'block';
```

Na div:

```
<div id="introd" class="hidden">
        <object data="oi.pdf" width="1000" height="550"></object>
        </div>
```

No CSS:

```
#introd{display: none;}
```